# How can I get my Angular2 DatePipe-formatted Date to update?

Tags: angular, angular2-pipe

Sample of the issue: http://plnkr.co/edit/7FeRoyyqDnjXpV9Q9Vpy?p=preview

```
import {Component, NgModule} from '@angular/core'
import {BrowserModule} from '@angular/platform-browser'

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <div>
      <h2>{{myDate}}</h2> <!-- THIS UPDATES AS EXPECTED -->
      <h2>{{myDate | date: 'longDate'}}</h2> <!-- THIS DOES NOT -->
      <a (click)="prevMonth()" href="javascript:;">Previous Month</a>
      <a (click)="nextMonth()" href="javascript:;">Next Month</a>
    </div>
  `,
})
export class App {
  myDate: Date;
  constructor() {
    this.myDate = new Date();
  }

  nextMonth() {
    this.myDate.setMonth(this.myDate.getMonth() + 1);
  }

  prevMonth() {
    this.myDate.setMonth(this.myDate.getMonth() - 1);
  }
}

@NgModule({
  imports: [ BrowserModule ],
  declarations: [ App ],
  bootstrap: [ App ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

When I pass my variable without using any pipes, it updates as expected.  But a DatePipe-formatted copy of that same variable does not update.  Does the pipe only update for observables?  Or can I use this with a standard Date type and expect it to update in realtime?

I do not see anything in the DatePipe API that suggests this as the expected behavior, but I've narrowed it down to the point where only the DatePipe could be affecting the bahavior in this way.  https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/index/DatePipe-pipe.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't work because the Angular2's [DatePipe](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/3dc61779f006959ef555999453d6983d647ebfcc/modules/%40angular/common/src/pipes/date_pipe.tshttps://github.com/angular/angular/blob/3dc61779f006959ef555999453d6983d647ebfcc/modules/%40angular/common/src/pipes/date_pipe.ts) is stateful (the `pure` property is set to `true` in the decorating function). Stateful pipes are applied only once on given object. You can change the pipe definition (not in A2 source of course) or make something to force the data change.

So the first way to solve it is to create and use new stateless Pipe:

```
@Pipe({name: 'myDate', pure: false})
export class MyDatePipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(value: any, pattern: string = 'mediumDate'): string {
    return (new DatePipe()).transform(value, pattern);
  }
}
```

I've prepared a [plnkr example](http://plnkr.co/edit/1EyMgV4LFU5x2ntf9XHa?p=preview).
It's simple and reusable, so I would recommend this solution for small data.

Although, it can be also solved by using [ChangeDetector](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/ChangeDetectorRef-class.html) and its `markForCheck()` method after every date update - this one would be more efficient.
Or as Dmitry said, just create new date object everytime you want to change the data.

Answer (score 2):

You need to reassign the date variable with new date reference.

`this.myDate = new Date(this.myDate.setMonth(this.myDate.getMonth() + 1));`

As stated in the documentation

> this pipe is marked as pure hence it will not be re-evaluated when the input is mutated. Instead users should treat the date as an immutable object and change the reference when the pipe needs to re-run

Answer (score 1):

Seems like pipes trigger updates not after linked object was updated but after the link for object was updated.

You can fix it by reassign **this.myDate** like below:

`this.myDate = new Date(this.myDate.setMonth(this.myDate.getMonth() + 1));`